# How do I make a String int terminator?

Tags: java

So im making everyone's fun game "Rock, Paper, Scissors" I got everything working, except having the while loop repeat 3 time before stopping. Well it does repeat 3 times and stops, but the 2nd and 3rd repeat the variables don't change. Take a look at the code and tell me what I'm doing wrong.
**UPDATE: Now that I have everything working how do I get this "Q" string to terminate the loop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors
{

    /**
     * (Insert a brief description that describes the purpose of this method)
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int compint;
        String usermove = "";
        String compmove = "";
        String winner = "";
        int count = 0;


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random gen = new Random();

        System.out.println("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
        int input = in.nextInt();       

        while (count < 3)
        {
            compint = gen.nextInt(3) + 1;

            if (input == 1)
            {
                usermove = "Rock";
            }
            else if (input == 2)
            {
                usermove = "Paper";
            }
            else if (input == 3)
            {
                usermove = "Scissors";
            }

            if (compint == 1)
            {
                compmove = "Rock";
            }
            else if (compint == 2)
            {
                compmove = "Paper";
            }
            else if (compint == 3)
            {
                compmove = "Scissors";
            }

            if (compint == input)
            {
                winner = "TIE";
            }
            else if (compint == 1 && input == 3)
            {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            }
            else if (compint == 2 && input == 1)
            {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            }
            else if (compint == 3 && input == 2)
            {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            }
            else
            {
                winner = "USER";
            }

            System.out.print("Computer: " + compmove + " | ");
            System.out.print("You: " + usermove + " | ");
            System.out.println("Winner: " + winner);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
            input = in.nextInt();
            count++;

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: 
1
Computer: Scissors | You: Rock | Winner: USER

Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: 
2
Computer: Rock | You: Paper | Winner: USER

Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: 
Q
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at RockPaperScissors.main(RockPaperScissors.java:102)
```

Comment: When hopping from one problem to the next, you should probably ask a new question instead of editing the existing, when the problem is a different one. Just be sure to make it clear that the problem is a new one, even if the code looks similar.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to repost this question as a new one, I tried your example and didn't get any luck. Maybe if I repost I'll get a better understanding from the masses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic that actually *does* anything with the input – all those `if` statements – is outside of the loop. With each iteration through the look, none of that logic is not actually executed. It all just happens first. Try this instead:

```
for (int count=0; count < 3; count++)
{
    int input = in.nextInt();
    int compint = gen.nextInt(3) + 1;

    // all the if statements and printing here
}
```

---

> **UPDATE: Now that I have everything working how do I get this "Q" string to terminate the loop?

You're getting an [`InputMismatchException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) when typing `Q` but the code calls `Scanner#nextInt()`. The docs are pretty clear on what the problem is:

> Thrown by a `Scanner` to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

It's basically the `Scanner`'s way of telling you "you asked for an `int` but the next token isn't one." You can add an additional check before the `nextInt()` calls, using [`Scanner#hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29), to verify that the next token actually *is* an int. If it's not an int, then you can plan on parsing it just as a string.

So instead of this:

```
input = in.nextInt();
```

Do something like this:

```
if (in.hasNextInt())
{
    input = in.nextInt();
} else if (in.hasNext("Q")) {
    // quit
}
```

Comment: Ok, by adding the if statements inside the while loop my first cycle comes out with no answers for the computer, user, or winner. 2nd and 3rd cycle work great.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm suppose to know how to use 'for loops' yet, but yes your example would be correct and I would say the easiest. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

seems you wanted to use `do - while loop`
it would work:

```
do{
       compint = gen.nextInt(3) + 1;

        System.out.println("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
        int input = in.nextInt();

        if (input == 1)
        {
            usermove = "Rock";
        }
        else if (input == 2)
        {
            usermove = "Paper";
        }
        else if (input == 3)
        {
            usermove = "Scissors";
        }

        if (compint == 1)
        {
            compmove = "Rock";
        }
        else if (compint == 2)
        {
            compmove = "Paper";
        }
        else if (compint == 3)
        {
            compmove = "Scissors";
        }

        if (compint == input)
        {
            winner = "TIE";
        }
        else if (compint == 1 && input == 3)
        {
            winner = "COMPUTER";
        }
        else if (compint == 2 && input == 1)
        {
            winner = "COMPUTER";
        }
        else if (compint == 3 && input == 2)
        {
            winner = "COMPUTER";
        }
        else
        {
            winner = "USER";
        }

            System.out.print("Computer: " + compmove + " | ");
            System.out.print("You: " + usermove + " | ");
            System.out.println("Winner: " + winner);
            System.out.println("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
            input = in.nextInt();
            count++;

        }while (count < 3);
```

Comment: Do - while would probably be more programming correct, but I did get it to work with just 'while loop'.
Thanks for fixing the error of 'compint=gen.nextInt(3)+1;' in my loop. I did leave that out and it was messing up the computer player.
Tell me how to give you some of the credit and I will.

Comment: @SkyVar as credit you can upvote the answer and later on can accept it also (if you find answer really solving your problem)